# Reading EEG text file into python

Tags: python, text-files

I am trying to create a classification algorithm for a neuromarketing task where brain activity was recorded while participants had to indicate a certain preference for a product. I have two different folders, one containing EEG data in multiple text files and one folder with the label (indicating like or dislike for the product). Each EEG text file corresponds to one label text file, basically mapping the EEG signal to the label.

This is how part of the content of an EEG text file looks like:

```
3689.743590 3701.025641 3835.384615 2734.871795 4188.205128 3781.025641 3699.487179 3702.564103 3818.461538 4218.461538 3737.435897 3764.102564 3763.589744 3926.666667
3699.487179 3704.615385 3844.615385 2701.538462 4184.615385 3785.641026 3708.717949 3707.692308 3829.230769 4216.923077 3751.282051 3770.769231 3776.923077 3934.871795
3708.717949 3718.974359 3861.025641 2679.487179 4185.641026 3785.641026 3717.435897 3716.410256 3845.641026 4219.487179 3747.692308 3767.692308 3776.410256 3942.564103
3719.487179 3755.384615 3871.282051 2688.717949 4184.615385 3793.846154 3730.769231 3731.794872 3867.179487 4217.948718 3765.128205 3773.846154 3794.358974 3945.128205
```

I am trying to figure out how to load and analyze the different EEG signals from the text files into python. I have only come across python packages that work on raw EEG data or other file formats.

Comment: This is a data reading issue, and it has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

```
import numpy as np

# Save data to a file.
d = """\
3689.743590 3701.025641 3835.384615 2734.871795 4188.205128 3781.025641 3699.487179 3702.564103 3818.461538 4218.461538 3737.435897 3764.102564 3763.589744 3926.666667
3699.487179 3704.615385 3844.615385 2701.538462 4184.615385 3785.641026 3708.717949 3707.692308 3829.230769 4216.923077 3751.282051 3770.769231 3776.923077 3934.871795
3708.717949 3718.974359 3861.025641 2679.487179 4185.641026 3785.641026 3717.435897 3716.410256 3845.641026 4219.487179 3747.692308 3767.692308 3776.410256 3942.564103
3719.487179 3755.384615 3871.282051 2688.717949 4184.615385 3793.846154 3730.769231 3731.794872 3867.179487 4217.948718 3765.128205 3773.846154 3794.358974 3945.128205"""
with open("data.txt", "w") as f:
    print(d, file=f)

# Load data
data = np.loadtxt("data.txt")
data.shape  # (4, 14)
```